# Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'string'

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I am receiving an "Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'string'" error on the third line of this code and I do not know why.

```
where (PRIORITiesItem.Prioid == null || PRIORITiesItem.Prioid.Contains("1%")) 
    && (SITEItem.Id == "TH" || SITEItem.Id == "NM")  
--> && (sv.Glseg.TrimStart == "703" || sv.Glseg.TrimStart == "704" || sv.Glseg.TrimStart == "705")        
    && (CREWItem.Crewid == null || !CREWItem.Crewid.Contains("2-%") && CREWItem.Crewid.Contains("MAINT") 
        || (CREWItem.Crewid.Contains("ELECT") || CREWItem.Crewid.Contains("INST")
    && !WORKORDERTYPEItem.Id.Contains("Standing")))
```

At first I thought that maybe it didn't like "==" so I chnaged it with "=" but that wasn't the problem.  besides, the line right above it uses "==" and it works just fine.  Glseg is a field within a table, not a method so it must not like the string.  Does anyone have any ideas where I am going wrong?

Comment: Is `TrimStart` a method or a property?

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs It's a method.  I see where I was going wrong.  Thank you

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In C#, those methods have to be called with `()`:

```
str.TrimStart() == "bla"
```

Comment: @ProgrammingNewbie as a general diagnostic rule, when you get an error message about a method group, and you didn't intend to do anything with a method group, it means you've forgotten the `()` parentheses to invoke a method.

Comment: @AakashM Thank you for that advice.  I should have seen what the problem was and am quite embarrassed that it was something so obvious. I'm in my first internship and this is the first time that I've dealt with code for such long periods of time and I've been  finding that after a while I seem to miss stupid little things like this.  Everything starts to blend and become one big mass.  I'll get better though.  Sorry for the waste of everyone's time.

Comment: No problem, it's one of the most cryptic of the error messages the C# compiler gives :)

Comment: @ProgrammingNewbie - I've been programming for a dozen years or more and need a konk on the head (this answer on SO) to realize the problem!  Yes, it is not too helpful of an error message, I agree AakashM.